# gradle error when Theme declare-styleable in two libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to compile an android project using the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'

        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:3.5.+'
        compile 'com.android:volley:1.0'
        compile 'org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.0'

}
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
:TestProject:processDebugResources
/home/lukas/apps/Splots_test/apps/TestProject/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:1622: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'switchStyle'.
:TestProject:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TestProject:processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':TestProject:processDebugResources'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

After looking at the generated values.xml I found that it was missing the declare-styleable "Theme" section of android-switch-backport.

This section is defined in both Appcompat and AndroidSwitchBackport, but only one of these is included in the final file:

```
lukas@lukas-Workstation:~/apps/Splots_test/apps$ grep -r 'declare-styleable name="Theme"' .
./TestProject/build/exploded-bundles/ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800.aar/res/values/values.xml:    <declare-styleable name="Theme">
./TestProject/build/exploded-bundles/OrgJrafAndroidSwitchBackport10.aar/res/values/values.xml:    <declare-styleable name="Theme">
```

Is there any way to tell gradle it should merge the attributes of both libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, I am the developer of the Switch Backport library, and this problem no longer exists since version 1.3.1.

(Make sure you include the correct repo when upgrading, since it is no longer maven central).

Answer (score 5):

I run into this problem,too.I think you need to change the attrs.xml file in android-switch-backport library.

Try changing this

```
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
        <attr name="switchStyle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="switchPreferenceStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

to this:

```
<declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="switchStyle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="switchPreferenceStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: this means recompiling the library ?

Comment: @Parhs Yes,we have to.Because there's a naming conflict between android-switch-backport library and app-compat library.

Comment: @Koruk how do you do that if you installed it from your build.gradle? You need to download the library itself? from where?

Comment: @JeremyD In my situation,I didn't install it from build.gradle.When it's the case you said,I think we really don't have access to the resources then,to my knowledge.